# How to post a question when wanting to pass on information as opposed to ask a question?

Tags: discussion, support, meta, asking-questions, scope

When wanting to post on meta to facilitate communication for example:

[Educating people to flag spam and not vote to close](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327636/educating-people-to-flag-spam-and-not-vote-to-close)

It can be a challenge creating a question and in some instances, the answer is within the question.

[Can flaggers include a link when flagging duplicated answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366616/can-flaggers-include-a-link-when-flagging-duplicated-answers)

Can we have some type of facility for writing posts like these or does the discussion tag covers these cases?

Comment: Can't you just create a FAQ?

Comment: Not sure what facility you expect... can you elaborate on that or give example of something out of SE?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm asking how to communicate with a community from within meta. Not the sort of question that can be asked from within the community. I'm wanting a protocol or idea.

Comment: a known way to communicate like you suggest seem to be [meta-tag:featured] tag, wonder what could be wrong with it

Comment: @gnat featured tag should be temporary, to give initial boost, not meant to be permanent. Think request here is about the general  case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having done that at [least once](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303019/stackoverflow-blog-isnt-that-great) on the mother meta, and and [on SU](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11930/the-super-user-blog-is-going-away). Its tricky but doable

In your specific cases I'd consider another option though -

Turn the question into a problem statement - "hey, so it happens that people flag stuff as a dupe of something that happens somewhere else, and we don't know where it is - it would be nice if folks supplied the link. That said, what does the community think, and do we have any other approaches to solve the problem?

Sometimes you might even get [a better answer you didn't really want but is](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12243/whats-our-threshold-for-profanity-in-comments) .

So lay out a problem definition - state that "this might work" and throw on a discussion flag and see what people discuss.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to a meta post, I would see that content as a blog post too if for educating and to get to a larger audience.

To make that possible I don't know if a MSE staff can get in touch with you, blog your content and state you as featured blogger, it could be nice.