# What can be done about the noisy blog posts?

Tags: discussion, blog, community-bulletin

I like the blog here. Or I mostly do.

[image: two blog posts shown]

It used to provide useful network wide information, or some relevant programming information.

Now it feels like there is 'content for content's sake' (no offence to the blog writers, I'm just not your target audience). This to me, feels like noise, that gets in the way of signal. I was happy for a blog once every 6-8 weeks (or longer).

Is there some way to filter out these blog posts in some way?

Or should I ignore all of them instead of checking each and everyone one for it's personal relevance to me.

Comment: I wouldn't say dupe but [deeply related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303019/stackoverflow-blog-isnt-that-great)

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard Nah, the "bulletin" tag means they show up on all tech sites... but you are correct that we do some targeting in the tagging. It only shows up network-wide if it's bearing the "announcements" tag.

Comment: @Catija cheers, didn't know that and checked only on arqade and movies. :/

Comment: "should I ignore all of them [or] checking each and everyone one" That's the choice currently.

Comment: Seems to be systematic of Stack Exchange, Inc. being more interested in revenue than providing a useful product.

Answer (score 3):

I feel that if they were tagged, searchable, and otherwise had some of the decent features that the rest of the QA site has (or a better-implementation of a blog), then "noise" would be less of an issue.

Comment: Perhaps some kind of "featured posts" tag on Meta? ;)