# Partner content on the blog - what's the value of these?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, advertising, blog

The Stack Overflow blog was historically a means of communication for the company to the community, and eventually ended up being a way for the company to communicate with potential users of their products in general. There was a heavy slant towards their own products (and while [I was critical of the quality of the writing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303019/135565), it was still centered around the SE ecosystem.

I refer to a recent blog post that appears to be entirely a [advertorial for a large credit card company](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/04/24/instantly-verify-your-customers-online-with-open-banking-apis/). While I guess there *could* be the slant of 'it’s for developers' - I don't really see any real links or relevance to Stack Overflow the company, its paid products, *or* the public sites. I also note this other one which seems to be a [sponsored post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/03/29/from-web2-to-web3-how-developers-can-upskill-and-build-with-blockchain/) for some blockchain product.

While I'm possibly not the target audience - what *is* the target audience of blogs like this - and what value do they bring? Unless the partner organisation is paying SO Inc well for this - since it goes above and beyond the 'usual' advertising (and the money goes somewhere of benefit), it feels like it somewhat devalues the brand for somewhat little benefit - and frankly I've heard some rather... spicy language around this from some network regulars.

I don't really see other companies putting third party content on their main blog outside some content aggregators - so what's the benefit here, and are these posts 'worth' it?